# Como posso fazer uma validação <select> em JavaScript para obrigar a marcar uma das opções?

Tags: javascript

Sim, Eu vi que tem muitas perguntas "PARECIDAS" mas nenhuma das respostas dadas parecia funcionar. Por isso vim aqui mostrar minha dúvida. Embora eu tenha testado muitos códigos. Acredito que o erro seja por serem respostas antigas ou que tenha alguma incompatibilidade de versão.

Bom, vou postar o código para que possam entender:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>TextoModificadorDeEstilos</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/> 
</head>
    <body>
        <h1>Formulário!</h1>


        <form name="formTrab" id="formTrabId" method="POST" action="/clientes">
    <fieldset><legend>Dados pessoais</legend>
        <label>Nome:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="nome" id="nomeId" placeholder="Digite seu nome" required="" maxlength="30" size="30">
        <br><br>
        <label>Endereço:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="endereco" id="enderecoId" placeholder="Digite seu endereço" required="" maxlength="50" size="50">
        <br>
        <label>Cidade:</label>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="cidade" id="cidadeId" placeholder="Digite sua cidade" required="" maxlength="50" size="50">
        <br>
        <br>
        Estado:
        <select name="estado" id="estadoId" onBlur="validaFormulario()">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Rio">Rio de Janeiro</option>
        <option value="SP">SãoPaulo</option>
        <option value="Floripa">Floriánopolis</option>
        <option value="Fortaleza">Fortaleza</option>
        <option value="Minas">Minas Gerais</option>
        <option value="Salvador">Salvador</option>
        <option value="Porto">Porto Seguro</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>

<fieldset><legend>Dados profissionais</legend>
        <label>Natureza do Cargo:</label>
        <br>
    Gerência<input id ="gerenciaId" name="gerencia" type="radio" value="1" checked>
    Financeiro<input id ="financeiroId" name="financeiro" type="radio" value="2">
    Recepção<input id ="recepcaoId" name="recepcao" type="radio" value="3">
    Administrativo<input id ="administrativoId" name="administrativo" type="radio" value="4" checked>
    Juridico<input id ="juridicoId" name="juridico" type="radio" value="5">
        <br><br>
        <label>Area de interesse:</label>
        <br>
    <input id ="computacaoId" name="computacao"  type="checkbox" value="1" checked>Computação
    <input id ="biologiaId" name="biologia" type="checkbox" value="2">Biologia
    <input id ="meioAmbienteId" name="meioAmbiente" type="checkbox" value="3">Meio Ambiente
    <input id ="engenhariaId" name="engenharia" type="checkbox" value="4" checked>Engenharia
    <input id ="historiaId" name="historia" type="checkbox" value="5">História
        <br>
        Mini-currículo: <textarea name="curriculo" id="curriculoId" style="height:140px; width: 350px;" ></textarea><br>
    </fieldset>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviarId">
    <input type="reset" value="Limpar" id="enviarId">

</form>

        <script>
        function validaFormulario(){
            var nome = formTrab.nome.value;
            var endereco = formTrab.endereco.value;
            var cidade = formTrab.cidade.value;
            var estado =formTrab.estado.value;

            if(nome.length <10){
                alert('Preencha o campo nome com no mínimo 10 letras .');
                formTrab.nome.focus();
                return false;
            }

            if(enderecoId.length <20){
                alert('Preencha o campo endereço com no mínimo 20 letras.');
                formTrab.endereco.focus();
                return false;
            }

            if(cidade == ""){
                alert('Preencha o campo senha com minimo 6 caracteres');
                formTrab.cidade.focus();
                return false;
            }


            if(estado==""){
                alert('Escolha um estado');
                formTrab.estado.focus();
                return false;
            }*/
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Agora eis a questão que não funciona, o meu form é capaz de identificar e pedir ao usuário que escreva nos campos vazios. No entanto, quando o select está vazio, não há impedimento de validação. Eu já tentei várias soluções que tem aqui no site. Mas acho que por ser iniciante e por não ter conhecimento de tecnologias como Jquery ou outros nomes que nem me lembro mas se relacionam com o "tema". Justifica-se o motivo pelo qual eu posso não ter entendido nada nas outras respostas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
  function vazio() {
     var x;
     x = document.getElementById("estadoId").value;
     if ((x == "")||(x == null)) {
        alert("Selecione uma opção");
        return false;
     };
  }
```

```html
        <select name="estado" id="estadoId" onBlur="return vazio()">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Rio">Rio de Janeiro</option>
        <option value="SP">SãoPaulo</option>
        <option value="Floripa">Floriánopolis</option>
        <option value="Fortaleza">Fortaleza</option>
        <option value="Minas">Minas Gerais</option>
        <option value="Salvador">Salvador</option>
        <option value="Porto">Porto Seguro</option>
        </select>
```

> a função tb pode ser disparada no `<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviarId"  onClick="return vazio()">`

```js
  function vazio() {
     var x;
     x = document.getElementById("estadoId").value;
     if ((x == "")||(x == null)) {
        alert("Selecione uma opção");
        return false;
     };
  }
```

```html
        <select name="estado" id="estadoId">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Rio">Rio de Janeiro</option>
        <option value="SP">SãoPaulo</option>
        <option value="Floripa">Floriánopolis</option>
        <option value="Fortaleza">Fortaleza</option>
        <option value="Minas">Minas Gerais</option>
        <option value="Salvador">Salvador</option>
        <option value="Porto">Porto Seguro</option>
        </select>

<input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviarId"  onClick="return vazio()">
```